# Do dark matter and dark energy have different physical laws from ordinary matter and energy?

Tags: string-theory, dark-matter, dark-energy

- What are [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) and [dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy)?
- Do dark matter and dark energy have different physical laws from ordinary matter and energy?
- **Can string theory explain their mechanisms?**

Comment: Please explain your question with background. Otherwise this is an extremely broad question.

Comment: @Ari i don't understand how to explain my question with background?

Comment: BTW, there isn't much connection between dark matter and dark energy, apart from the word "dark" in their names.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of the three questions I keep my answers similarly broad:

> do dark matter and dark energy have different physical laws from ordinary matter and energy?

No. It is the beauty of science that so far all laws have been found to be universal. This is a version of the "cosmological principle". That said, their are distinguished by their particular features, but that is no different from an apple and an orange being two different things and still obeying the same physical laws.

> What are dark matter and dark energy?

Dark matter is the name for forms of matter that so far have only been evidenced through their gravitational interaction. In particular, dark matter has not been "seen" directly. There is five times more stuff in the universe in the form of this dark matter, compared to the normal matter that we know about.

Dark energy is a name for the observed fact that the universe not only expands, but that this expansion accelerates.

> can string theory explain their mechanisms?

Depending on the particular model, string theory can make statements about either, though in general, one could have string theory without dark matter or dark energy, and dark matter and dark energy could exist without string theory.